# How to connect to mongo sharding cluster

Tags: java, mongodb, sharding

In a regular replica set, we can implement Java code connect to the replica set in case on server is down, the client still works without modifying code. In a sharding cluster, the cluster can only connect to one routing server, if I have three routing servers in the sharding cluster, how can I have the same client as in the replica set case? I don't want to modify the client too much.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from mongo doc, it is the same as replica set.
http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html